# Matlab Efficient and Quick Sampling from 2D Matrix

Tags: matlab, sampling

Using MatLab, I have a 2D matrix which I want to sample from.  The position are known and fixed every time.

A nested For loop is slow.  Currently I am using logical indexing e.g.

```
cords = [ 1 0 1; 0 0 0 ]; cords = logical(cords)
data = aMatrix(cords);
```

My main question is: is there an even faster method than this?

Another query I have, by using logical indexing, does that sample that data in the same order every time, this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical indexing is generally faster than linear indexing or subscripting, probably on account of the usual call to `find`.  If you have the logical matrix, use it. If you have have linear indexes, use them. Don't try to convert just to speed up the actual indexing step.

The order of the output `data` obtained from logical indexing will be in the same order as the indexes returned by `find(cords)` (linear indexing).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst logical indexing is straightforward and fast, if you only have a small number of known points to extract you might still consider linear indexing for sheer simplicity:

```
data = aMatrix([1 5]);
```

For less trivial cases, [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) will help.